# Html + Java | receiving 0 from input type="time"

Tags: java, html, spring, input, thymeleaf

I'm trying to make an webApp, where you should pick the time you woke up. I'm using Spring, with Thymeleaf as the connecter between my java and html. But no matter what time i choose, it returns 0.

My StartDay Class:

```
/* ----------------------------
|        StartDay Class       |
------------------------------ */

@Entity
@Table(name = "start_day")
public class StartDay {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "start_day_id")
private int startDayId;
@Column(name = "age_in_days", nullable = false)
private int ageInDays;
@Column(name = "day_created", nullable = false)
private String dayCreated;
@Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
private String username;
@Column(name = "dream_remembered", nullable = false)
private boolean dreamRemembered;
@Column(name = "nightmare", nullable = false)
private boolean nightmare;
@Column(name = "waking_time", nullable = false)
private int wakingTime;
@Column(name = "good_night_of_sleep", nullable = false)
private boolean goodNightOfSleep;



/* ------------------------------
|        Getter & Setter        |
------------------------------ */

public String getDayCreated() {
    return dayCreated;
}
public void setDayCreated(String dayCreated) {
    this.dayCreated = dayCreated;
}

public int getAgeInDays() {
    return ageInDays;
}
public void setAgeInDays(int ageInDays) {
    this.ageInDays = ageInDays;
}

public boolean isDreamRemembered() {
    return dreamRemembered;
}
public void setDreamRemembered(boolean dreamRemembered) {
    this.dreamRemembered = dreamRemembered;
}

public boolean isNightmare() {
    return nightmare;
}
public void setNightmare(boolean nightmare) {
    this.nightmare = nightmare;
}

public int getWakingTime() {
    return wakingTime;
}
public void setWakingTime(int wakingTime) {
    this.wakingTime = wakingTime;
}

public boolean isGoodNightOfSleep() {
    return goodNightOfSleep;
}
public void setGoodNightOfSleep(boolean goodNightOfSleep) {
    this.goodNightOfSleep = goodNightOfSleep;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String userId) {
    this.username = userId;
}

/* ------------------------------
|          CONSTRUCTOR          |
------------------------------ */

public StartDay(int ageInDays, String dayCreated, String username, boolean dreamRemembered, boolean nightmare, int wakingTime, boolean goodNightOfSleep) {
    this.ageInDays = ageInDays;
    this.dayCreated = dayCreated;
    this.username = username;
    this.dreamRemembered = dreamRemembered;
    this.nightmare = nightmare;
    this.wakingTime = wakingTime;
    this.goodNightOfSleep = goodNightOfSleep;
}

public StartDay() {
}

}
```

My start-dag.html page:

```
<form th:action="@{/normal/start-dag}" th:object="${startDay}" method="post">
    <div>
        <p>Hvad tid stod du op?</p>
        <input type="time" name="wakingTime">

        <p>Har du sovet godt?</p>
        <!--<input type="checkbox" name="goodNightOfSleep"><span>Ja</span>-->

        <p>Kan du huske hvad du drømte?</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dreamRemembered"><span>Ja</span>

        <p>Var det et mareridt?</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="nightmare"><span>Ja</span>

        <input type="hidden" name="username" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ageInDays" />
        <input type="hidden" name="dayCreated" />

        <input type="submit" value="Start dag">
    </div>
</form>
```

Any help/suggestions is appreciated!

UPDATE #1 – More code added

My StartDayController

```
// Start\create day
    @GetMapping("/normal/start-dag")
    public  String opretGoal(Model model){
        StartDay startDay = new StartDay();
        model.addAttribute("startDay", startDay);
        return "normal/start-dag";
    }
    @PostMapping("/normal/start-dag")
    public String opretGoal(@ModelAttribute StartDay startDay, BindingResult bindingResult){

        startDayService.createGoalOfTheDay(startDay);

        return "redirect:/normal/menu";
    }
```

[image: Test on frontEnd]

Comment: How are you sending the value to the Java endpoint. What is reading said value? Could you please post some more code

Comment: I added my controller, is that enough or any other specific code needed? ill post it right away

Comment: Please also the `StartDay` class if possible. Also, are you sending more values than just the `wakingTime` to the endpoint?

Comment: Yes i do! Everything else is sending the correct values, only the time sending 0 no matter what. All my code is added :)

Comment: Can you see if the value is really sent to the endpoint? In chrome using F12 and then looking for the request in the network tab. That way it is possible to determine if the frontend or the backend makes something wrong

Comment: I have added a picture telling it sends the value, i think :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Column(name = "waking_time", nullable = false)
private int wakingTime;
```

you are sending 08:00 as input and accepting value as int. You can either accept like

```
@DateTimeFormat
@Column(name = "waking_time", nullable = false)
private Date wakingTime;
```

and covert it into desired format.

or if you want to accept the time as 08:00. accept it as String.

```
@Column(name = "waking_time", nullable = false)
private String wakingTime;
```

Comment: Thank you! Im gonna take it in as a String for saving in the DB :) Or would you rather suggest doing it as a Date?

Comment: Whats your usecase? If you are going to do any operations on the wakingTime save it as date.